# Stretch Width of WPF RichTextBox within a TreeView

Tags: c#, wpf, treeview, richtextbox

My objective is simply to have a RichTextBox consume the entire row width inside a TreeView. The XAML below will produce a TreeView with a RichTextBox element, but the width is only 1 character wide.

I have encountered the posts below concerning width Bugs in RichTextBox.  These issues may have been fixed since a standalone RichTextBox has the expected width.  Despite this I still tried creating Grids, setting Alignments to Stretch, and binding the FlowDocument PageWidth to parent without success.

[NEW]
I am adding a description of my application in case some would like to propose RTB alternatives.  I have a TreeView that contains between 10-1000 RTB nodes.  TextBox and TextBlock are not practical because I need full formatting and user editing.

[WPF RichTextBox with no width set](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/350863/wpf-richtextbox-with-no-width-set)

[A WPF RichTextBox + Button in a StackPanel => what a mess?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3891653/a-wpf-richtextbox-button-in-a-stackpanel-what-a-mess)

```
<TreeView>
    <RichTextBox>
        <FlowDocument>
            <Paragraph>
                <Run>
                    Hello
                </Run>
            </Paragraph>
        </FlowDocument>
    </RichTextBox>
</TreeView>
```

Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you stated this is a [known issue](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/354442/wpf-richtextbox-wrapping-fails-in-listbox)

The workaround provided is:

```
<TreeView Name="RTBContainer" >
 <RichTextBox  Width="{Binding Path=ActualWidth, ElementName=RTBContainer, Mode=OneWay}">
       <FlowDocument >
         <Paragraph>
           <Run>
               Hello
          </Run>
        </Paragraph>
     </FlowDocument>
  </RichTextBox>
</TreeView>
```

Comment: I am not sure what else you have in your app that may impact this. In my sandbox with just this control I do not see this delay.

Comment: Thanks this does solve my initial problem but creates a performance issue. With the Binding a 2 second delay occurs each time you type a character - Unacceptable. Does anyone know what causes this delay and how it can be fixed? I added an application description to my post in case someone would like to propose a RTB Alternative..

Comment: I had one more layer in my RTB sample project `<TreeViewItem Name="RTBContainer>`, which made all the difference.  If I Bind to the TreeView Element instead of TreeViewItem everything works fast (Not sure why).  In practice I will have to do a clever bind with Ancestor.  This is because my RTB is the toplevel of a UserControl (No width property), which later gets injected into a TreeView using Code and MEF.  Anyway thanks for your help (Marked Answered)!

Answer (score 1):

Your problem stems from the TreeViewItem default template. A TreeViewItem element wraps any content placed in a TreeView.  The TreeViewItem's template is Grid containing three columns with the width of the first two set as Auto while width of the third is set as *. The element holding the Header content is in the second column and its content alignment set to Left.

I've extracted the template for the TreeViewItem and modified it so that the content container for the header spans the second and third columns and has its content alignment set to stretch.

(This is a modified clone of the WPF template so it's a bit lengthly)

```
<TreeView>
    <TreeView.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="TreeViewItem">
            <!-- set the headers content to stretch -->
            <Setter Property="Control.HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="TreeViewItem" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" xmlns:s="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib" xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
                        <Grid>
                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" MinWidth="19" />
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                                <RowDefinition />
                            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <ToggleButton IsChecked="False" ClickMode="Press" Name="Expander">
                                <ToggleButton.Style>
                                    <Style TargetType="ToggleButton">
                                        <Style.Resources>
                                            <ResourceDictionary />
                                        </Style.Resources>
                                        <Setter Property="UIElement.Focusable">
                                            <Setter.Value>
                                                <s:Boolean>False</s:Boolean>
                                            </Setter.Value>
                                        </Setter>
                                        <Setter Property="FrameworkElement.Width">
                                            <Setter.Value>
                                                <s:Double>16</s:Double>
                                            </Setter.Value>
                                        </Setter>
                                        <Setter Property="FrameworkElement.Height">
                                            <Setter.Value>
                                                <s:Double>16</s:Double>
                                            </Setter.Value>
                                        </Setter>
                                        <Setter Property="Control.Template">
                                            <Setter.Value>
                                                <ControlTemplate TargetType="ToggleButton">
                                                    <Border Padding="5,5,5,5" Background="#00FFFFFF" Width="16" Height="16">
                                                        <Path Fill="#00FFFFFF" Stroke="#FF989898" Name="ExpandPath">
                                                            <Path.Data>
                                                                <PathGeometry Figures="M0,0L0,6L6,0z" />
                                                            </Path.Data>
                                                            <Path.RenderTransform>
                                                                <RotateTransform Angle="135" CenterX="3" CenterY="3" />
                                                            </Path.RenderTransform>
                                                        </Path>
                                                    </Border>
                                                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                                                        <Trigger Property="UIElement.IsMouseOver">
                                                            <Setter Property="Shape.Stroke" TargetName="ExpandPath">
                                                                <Setter.Value>
                                                                    <SolidColorBrush>#FF1BBBFA</SolidColorBrush>
                                                                </Setter.Value>
                                                            </Setter>
                                                            <Setter Property="Shape.Fill" TargetName="ExpandPath">
                                                                <Setter.Value>
                                                                    <SolidColorBrush>#00FFFFFF</SolidColorBrush>
                                                                </Setter.Value>
                                                            </Setter>
                                                            <Trigger.Value>
                                                                <s:Boolean>True</s:Boolean>
                                                            </Trigger.Value>
                                                        </Trigger>
                                                        <Trigger Property="ToggleButton.IsChecked">
                                                            <Setter Property="UIElement.RenderTransform" TargetName="ExpandPath">
                                                                <Setter.Value>
                                                                    <RotateTransform Angle="180" CenterX="3" CenterY="3" />
                                                                </Setter.Value>
                                                            </Setter>
                                                            <Setter Property="Shape.Fill" TargetName="ExpandPath">
                                                                <Setter.Value>
                                                                    <SolidColorBrush>#FF595959</SolidColorBrush>
                                                                </Setter.Value>
                                                            </Setter>
                                                            <Setter Property="Shape.Stroke" TargetName="ExpandPath">
                                                                <Setter.Value>
                                                                    <SolidColorBrush>#FF262626</SolidColorBrush>
                                                                </Setter.Value>
                                                            </Setter>
                                                            <Trigger.Value>
                                                                <s:Boolean>True</s:Boolean>
                                                            </Trigger.Value>
                                                        </Trigger>
                                                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                                                </ControlTemplate>
                                            </Setter.Value>
                                        </Setter>
                                    </Style>
                                </ToggleButton.Style>
                            </ToggleButton>
                            <!-- other problem was here set the Borders ColumnSpan to 2 -->
                            <Border BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding Border.BorderThickness}" Padding="{TemplateBinding Control.Padding}" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding Border.BorderBrush}" Background="{TemplateBinding Panel.Background}" Name="Bd" SnapsToDevicePixels="True" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" >
                                <ContentPresenter Content="{TemplateBinding HeaderedContentControl.Header}" ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding HeaderedContentControl.HeaderTemplate}" ContentStringFormat="{TemplateBinding HeaderedItemsControl.HeaderStringFormat}" ContentSource="Header" Name="PART_Header" HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding Control.HorizontalContentAlignment}" SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding UIElement.SnapsToDevicePixels}" />
                            </Border>
                            <ItemsPresenter Name="ItemsHost" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" />
                        </Grid>
                        <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                            <Trigger Property="TreeViewItem.IsExpanded">
                                <Setter Property="UIElement.Visibility" TargetName="ItemsHost">
                                    <Setter.Value>
                                        <x:Static Member="Visibility.Collapsed" />
                                    </Setter.Value>
                                </Setter>
                                <Trigger.Value>
                                    <s:Boolean>False</s:Boolean>
                                </Trigger.Value>
                            </Trigger>
                            <Trigger Property="ItemsControl.HasItems">
                                <Setter Property="UIElement.Visibility" TargetName="Expander">
                                    <Setter.Value>
                                        <x:Static Member="Visibility.Hidden" />
                                    </Setter.Value>
                                </Setter>
                                <Trigger.Value>
                                    <s:Boolean>False</s:Boolean>
                                </Trigger.Value>
                            </Trigger>
                            <Trigger Property="TreeViewItem.IsSelected">
                                <Setter Property="Panel.Background" TargetName="Bd">
                                    <Setter.Value>
                                        <DynamicResource ResourceKey="{x:Static SystemColors.HighlightBrushKey}" />
                                    </Setter.Value>
                                </Setter>
                                <Setter Property="TextElement.Foreground">
                                    <Setter.Value>
                                        <DynamicResource ResourceKey="{x:Static SystemColors.HighlightTextBrushKey}" />
                                    </Setter.Value>
                                </Setter>
                                <Trigger.Value>
                                    <s:Boolean>True</s:Boolean>
                                </Trigger.Value>
                            </Trigger>
                            <MultiTrigger>
                                <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                                    <Condition Property="TreeViewItem.IsSelected">
                                        <Condition.Value>
                                            <s:Boolean>True</s:Boolean>
                                        </Condition.Value>
                                    </Condition>
                                    <Condition Property="Selector.IsSelectionActive">
                                        <Condition.Value>
                                            <s:Boolean>False</s:Boolean>
                                        </Condition.Value>
                                    </Condition>
                                </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                                <Setter Property="Panel.Background" TargetName="Bd">
                                    <Setter.Value>
                                        <DynamicResource ResourceKey="{x:Static SystemColors.ControlBrushKey}" />
                                    </Setter.Value>
                                </Setter>
                                <Setter Property="TextElement.Foreground">
                                    <Setter.Value>
                                        <DynamicResource ResourceKey="{x:Static SystemColors.ControlTextBrushKey}" />
                                    </Setter.Value>
                                </Setter>
                            </MultiTrigger>
                            <Trigger Property="UIElement.IsEnabled">
                                <Setter Property="TextElement.Foreground">
                                    <Setter.Value>
                                        <DynamicResource ResourceKey="{x:Static SystemColors.GrayTextBrushKey}" />
                                    </Setter.Value>
                                </Setter>
                                <Trigger.Value>
                                    <s:Boolean>False</s:Boolean>
                                </Trigger.Value>
                            </Trigger>
                        </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </TreeView.ItemContainerStyle>
    <RichTextBox HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch">
        <FlowDocument>
            <Paragraph>
                <Run>
                    Hello
                </Run>
            </Paragraph>
        </FlowDocument>
    </RichTextBox>
</TreeView>
```