# Prevent RichTextBox from growing in height

Tags: wpf, richtextbox

How can I prevent a RichTextBox from growing in height when the text reaches the end of the line?

I have a RichTextBox where I set `AcceptsReturn=False`. When `AcceptsReturn=False`, I set `Height=23.2766666666667`. When I do not set the Width in XAML or codebehind, the text wraps after each character. I would like to have a RichTextBox that can grow or shrink in width with its containing element, but doesn't grow in height when the text reaches this width.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/607252/168117

> Try binding the FlowDocument's width (one way) to the width of the container RichTextBox.
>
> Worked for me...